# Date & Time Picker can't be set to blank

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I am creating a Windows Phone 8.1 Universal App. I have a combobox and datepicker & timepicker on XAML Page. My need is to keep the datepicker blank when I select some value in Combobox. Don't want to show anything not even default date and time.

But unfortunately, I didn't found any way to set it to blank. If no values assign to date/time Picker control, it shows only default date value in datepicker and default time in timepicker.

Please suggest, how can I achieve this ?

Comment: Have you thought about using [TimePickerFlyout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.timepickerflyout.aspx)? Assign it for example to a button and you can define any content, even epmty. The second way is to change default template of date/time picker.

Comment: Hey, how can we done with it by second way ?

Comment: As I've checked, it's not so simple, hence the default flyout changes button's content regardless what you define in it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use [DatePickerFlyout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.datepickerflyout.aspx). With this you can put anything as your Button's content. For example like this:

```xml
<Button Content="Click">
    <Button.Flyout>
        <DatePickerFlyout />
    </Button.Flyout>
</Button>
```